# How to integrate spring mvc project with angular 2?

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc

I created my spring mvc project without using maven ,now i like to create a single page with angular 2 ,so i created the page with angular 2 .now i want these angular 2 to integrate with spring mvc

Comment: what specifically do you mean by integration? is it dev build setup integration? At runtime, angular code running in the browser is coupled to the spring mvc based backed only at the REST API level.

Comment: I created my spring mvc project without using maven ,now i like to create a single page with angular 2 ,so i created the page with angular 2 .now i want these angular 2 to integrate with spring mvc

Comment: So is it a packaging issue (do you want to serve your angular page with spring)?

Comment: Yes i want to serve the angular 2 with spring mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't use maven, the only solution I see is to compile your `Angular 2` application with

```
ng build
```

This will generate the `dist` folder.
Copy that folder to the `target` folder of your spring application.

But I don't understand why you don't want to use a build automation tool.